# Strange RegEx behaviour - AND/OR operator

Tags: regex, kapow

I am working with Software Robotics in Kofax Kapow Design Studio. This tooling supports, well... it says it supports standard regex.

I have a hardcoded variable called: RegEx (value hard set: EUR)
In the evaluate tool I have the following RegEx set:

```
RegEx == ("EUR"|"USD"|"CAD")
```

The tool returns with this error:

```
Error in line 1 character 16: Illegal character '|
```

Isnt this the most basic and/or evaluation based on a hardcoded variable? Why is the tool returning this error?

Bad: https://i.stack.imgur.com/347jU.png

Good: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0dWk.png

Comment: Have you tried (EUR|USD|CAD)?

Comment: One line of code totally out of context is usually meaningless. You may want to expand your code sample to include variable declarations and surrounding lines of code.

Comment: Not sure what the quotes are doing there, but even if interpreted literally, the pattern should still be valid.  I suggest that your code is broken, maybe you didn't even phrase that line correctly.

Comment: YES EUR|USD|CAT without quotation marks have been tested but not succesful.

Comment: Are you sure `RegEx == ("EUR|USD|CAD")` does not work? Please share the tool documentation link.

Comment: Just try `EUR|USD|CAD`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pattern matching instead. The following pattern should work fine and there is no need to use quotation marks for string matching in pattern matching option of `Kofax Kapow`

```
EUR|USD|CAD
```

Answer (score 0):

Expressions don't handle regex natively.

You can use `replacePattern("EUR","^(EUR|USD|CAD)$","foobar") == "foobar"`

`foobar` can be any string, even an empty string.